# Excel Macro: Set the formula of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to insert a row into all selected sheets and then set some of the values to equal the values in another sheet. I've managed to insert the row using the following code, but I'm getting stuck trying to set the values. Without a macro, I'd simply enter `=InputC7` Input being the name of the first sheet in the workbook.

```
Sub InsertRows()
'
' InsertRows Macro
' Inserts rows into all selected sheets at the same position
'

    Dim CurrentSheet As Object

    ' Loop through all selected sheets.
    For Each CurrentSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        ' Insert 1 row at row 7 of each sheet.
        CurrentSheet.Range("a7:a7").EntireRow.Insert
        CurrentSheet.Range("c7").Value =Input!C7 'this is not working
    Next CurrentSheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the value from the sheet named "Input" you can do this:

```
CurrentSheet.Range("C7").Value = Sheets("Input").Range("C7").Value
```

If you want the formula "=Input!C7" you can do this:

```
CurrentSheet.Range("C7").Formula = "=Input!C7"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Formula` instead of the `Value` property, and the text should be quoted:

```
CurrentSheet.Range("c7").Formula "=Input!C7"
```